# Handle diff content type in node application

Tags: node.js, express, content-type, body-parser

I am developing a api in nodejs which will consume by different application. different application will make call with different content type. I have use the body-parser to parsing req data.

I like to have some middleware to handle the content type and convert  data in consistent format so that my controller will work properly.

If if got the call with the **'text/plain;charset=UTF-8'** then before calling my controller i have to  **parse data to json format**.

also i have to add some **encoding** before sending data. in same function i will decode the my data also

please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: `req.headers['content-type']` would give you the value of that header, and then you'd have to use a condition/switch to determine what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this function to server.ts to handle the different response type

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.headers['content-type'] == "text/plain;charset=UTF-8") {
        req.body = JSON.parse(req.body)
    }
    return next();
});
```